# Simple jquery not working to print the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

Here is a simple code which takes input and print it on the same page. But it is not working when I click on button. Please help regarding this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeHTML() {
    $("#withjQuery").html($("#theInput").val());
}

</script>

<body>
<input type='text' id='theInput' value='Write here' />

<input type='button' onClick='changeHTML();' value='See what you wrote with jQuery.html'/>

<div id="withjQuery"></div>

</body>

</head>
```

Comment: include this betwen your head `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have jQuery library included in the page

Add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

ex

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function changeHTML() {
    $("#withjQuery").html($("#theInput").val());
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<input type='text' id='theInput' value='Write here' />

<input type='button' onClick='changeHTML();' value='See what you wrote with jQuery.html'/>

<div id="withjQuery"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/25Q9j/)

Comment: +1. I actually commented that it is working for me and only then realized the library is missing :)

Comment: @Harry for me too... I tried a fiddle first... only then realized that